# AngularJS when use shared directive to isolate directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

Sometimes I need to pass multiple complex objects to directives.

My question is which way of work is better, as your opinion, or maybe as a standard, if there is.

Doing so:

```
<my-directive
 config="{
   ... 
 }"
></my-directive>
```

And then having the config in the directive like that:

```
scope: {
  config: "="
}
```

OR

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

and then having the data in the scope like that:

```
// controller.js
$scope.config = {
  ...
};

// my-directive.js
scope: true,
link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
  console.log($scope.config); // the obj
}
```

And sub question: If I use the first method - using isolated scope, and I send config (object), is there a way to parse it more practically? for example:

```
// my-directive.js 
$scope = Object.assign($scope, $scope.config);
delete $scope.config;
console.log($scope.some_key_that_was_in_config_obj); // some value
```

Comment: It better if you bind your  scope from  controller.. but may I know what you want do ? or else provide some jsfidlle or plunker.

Comment: @MayankVadiya You mean by using `scope:true`?

Comment: Use one-way binding with `"<"` for inputs. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) and [AngularJS Developer Guide - Isolating the Scope of a Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).

Comment: The setting of the config using `scope: true` has a fatal flaw. We can only use it once within a given scope.

Comment: The first approach is actually much slower when working with large data sets, as angular will be parsing the entire input and looking for patterns etc.

Comment: @georgeawg it should be using different names for different directives's configs.

Comment: @JakubJudas using isolated scope is slower than using it shared? explain please.

Comment: No, not isolated scope, but actually inlining the data as shown on line 2, i.e. <my-directive config="{...}">. The ideal situation would be to have an isolated scope, but pass the data as a variable - so both $scope.config=… in the parent controler and then <my-directive config="config"> and the directive should accept config as a parameter. Isolating a scope is always preferable.

Comment: @JakubJudas Got you. But what to do when generating the <my-directive> via ng-repeat? something like this: `<div ng-repeat="x in array"><my-directive config="the value that should be here is not generated via the main controller.js file"></my-directive></div>`

Comment: Where do you get the config value?

Comment: The config value is object of mix of data, based on sync hand put data and based on some data returning from the remote server.

Comment: I'd compose it in the controller of the component that is doing the ng-repeat.